# How to calculate (a^b) mod c where b is large and c is not prime?

Tags: math

**a^ b mod c**
I know how to solve if c is prime, what will be the approach if c is not prime.
Any mathematical approach.

Comment: is this about symbolically solving a mathematical problem, or is it a request for a C/ C++ program that numerically calculates the answer?

Comment: C/C++ program - is there any approach ?

Comment: Change the category to C++ and you will get a lot of C++ visitors instead of people looking forward to a math problem and then being annoyed and voting your question down :D

Comment: Or rather, math AND c++

Comment: What exactly is input and what the desired output?

Comment: You should probably explore Eulers totient function.

Comment: What are you solving for: a, b, c, or calculating a^b (mod c)?

Comment: Can you ensure that a and c are coprime? How large can the values be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the factorization of `c` is known, you can compute the [Euler totient value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_theorem) `phi(c)` and know that with that number, but only if `a` and `c` have no common divisors,

```
a^b == a^( b mod phi(c) )  mod c
```

Thus if `b` is, as in your original edit, some very very large Fibonacci number, you have to compute this number with the algorithm of your choice with all arithmetic operations `mod phi(c)`. This at the same time ensures that the exponent stays inside the same number format as used for `c` and that the complexity of the exponentiation is reduced.

Comment: Nitpick: your formula may not be valid if `a` and `c` are not relatively prime.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: You are right, and WP states this clearly. Now inserted.